# Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client [dev.start] at ServerResponse.setHeader

Tags: javascript, node.js, rest, typescript, http-headers

I have a REST API using Nodejs and when logging in I get this error in the console:

```
Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client
at ServerResponse.setHeader (_http_outgoing.js:481:11)
at ServerResponse.header (/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:767:10)
```

And in my controller I have the login function:

```
export async function login(req, res, next) {
  res.status(HTTPStatus.OK).json(req.user.toAuthJSON());
  return next();
}
```

And here is the Login route:

```
routes.post(
  '/login',
  validate(AuthenticationController.validation.login),
  authLocal,
  AuthenticationController.login,
);
```

I tried adding the headers in the main index file:

```
  app.use ((res) => {
    res.header('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded')
  })
```

but the server just hangs. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Though I'm not expert in nodejs as a server platform, I can tell you that the problem is that you're setting the headers once you've started sending the response to the client. The headers are the first thing sent, so you cannot change them after responding.

Comment: what code is there in validate(AuthenticationController.validation.login)? I am not sure in nodejs but in PHP if you have some echo statement before sending header then it throws error like headers already sent.

Comment: @SatishSojitra It is basically some validation on password and email

Comment: @OscarPaz Yeah that is what I thought too, but I am not setting any headers after the start of the response

Comment: @peterSzoldan - Share more code, as it's not clear whats in AuthenticationController.validation.login, authLocal

Comment: @VikashSharma I just approved an edit, and corrected a minor grammatical error. The OP is SoftwareNinja I presume you meant your comment to him?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will see this error if your code is trying to respond twice to the same request.

From your code, I suspect the login handler.

```
export async function login(req, res, next) {
  res.status(HTTPStatus.OK).json(req.user.toAuthJSON()); // Sends the response first
  return next(); // Invokes the next handler, which will also respond
}
```

To fix this, return immediately after sending the first request.

```
export async function login(req, res, next) {
  return res.status(HTTPStatus.OK).json(req.user.toAuthJSON()); // Sends the response first
}
```

Comment: That fixed the problem. Thanks :)